# How can i get return value(int) in Unity3d coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, return, coroutine

How to get return value in coroutine?
But, The getElapseSecond() function should not be inside the coroutine.

```
 WWW www;
public IEnumerator requestNowTime()
{
    www = new WWW(url);

    yield return www;
}


public IEnumerator getNowTime()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(requestNowTime());
}

public int getElapseSecond()
{
    StartCoroutine(getNowTime()); 
    // You are trying to load data from a www stream which has not completed the download yet.

    int totalSeconds = 0;
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(www.text);
    TimeSpan compareTime = dt - Convert.ToDateTime(getTime());
    totalSeconds = (int)compareTime.TotalSeconds;  

    return totalSeconds;  //0
}
```

Comment: Make your `getElapseSecond` a coroutine function too then use `Action` as shown in the dupicate. You can also keep it as the void function it but then use a callback function as described in Isuka's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't simply be able to wait the result of a coroutine in a normal function, except if you want your game to freeze until your answer is there by using a while loop or such.

What I can suggest you is the following strategy: use callbacks. Callbacks are functions you will call when your current function/coroutine is done working. After you received your `WWW` parameter in `requestNowTime`, call a function which will compute the elapsed time. And in that same function, when you will be done computing, use a callback which would be a function of the original caller which will be able to use the result as expected first.

```
WWW www;

// Call this function to start the computing process
public void ProcessElapsedSeconds(Action functionToCallWhenDone)
{
    StartCoroutine(requestNowTime(functionToCallWhenDone));
}

public IEnumerator requestNowTime(Action callback)
{
    www = new WWW(url);

    OnTimeReceived(www, functionToCallWhenDone);
}  

void OnTimeReceived(WWW www, Action functionToCallWhenDone)
{
    int totalSeconds = 0;
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(www.text);
    TimeSpan compareTime = dt - Convert.ToDateTime(getTime());
    totalSeconds = (int)compareTime.TotalSeconds;  

    functionToCallWhenDone(totalSeconds);
}
```